# How can I apply security-opt when creating a container using the podman RESTful api

Tags: rest, podman

I'm interfacing with podman via the RESTful api [here](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/_static/api.html?version=v4.2#tag/containers/operation/ContainerCreateLibpod) and I need to apply a security-opt ( --security-opt label=disable ) when I call create container as I can on the command line, but the REST api doesn't seem to support it.  Is there any way to get this applied?